# OutputCheckBox?

Tags: visualforce

This may be a easy question for some of you, I really hope so. 
I'm trying to get an "output Checkbox". I'm building a visualforce page and I need to expose check boxes results on that page. 
I tried the "outputField" but it doesn't show the tick box.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Custom Field" for="customField"/>
    <apex:outputField id="customField" value="{!Account.customField__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

On that code the CustomField__c is a tick box.

So, how can I accomplish this, because there is not an outputCheckBox and the inputCheckBox is not going to work either?

Comment: Please ignore this question. It is working correctly now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my understanding,  you want to display a checkbox with checked mark and it's a read only field.  You can achieve that by doing like this:

`<apex:inputcheckbox value="{!Account.customField__c}" label="Same as Above" selected="True" disabled ="true">`

If it's not can you explain clearly what you want to display on vf page

Comment: Hi Kiran, thanks for your answer but it works fine with the outputField. I found an error on the check box field name, so that is why it was not showing up.

Comment: could you just post the error you are getting so that we can analysise the issue to get any solution

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this:

```
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!r.isSuccess}" layout="block">
                <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(r.isSuccess)}" layout="block">
                <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
            </apex:outputPanel>
```

Then you don't need an apex:form tag.

Answer (score 3):

What about using the following code instead?

```
<apex:column headerValue="Custom Field">

<img src="/img/checkbox_{!IF(!Account.customField__c == TRUE, '', 'un')}checked.gif" />

</apex:column>
```

Comment: You can drop `== TRUE`. It will evaluate the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a better answer.

```
<apex:inputcheckbox value="{!FieldName}"  onclick="return false" />
```

Instead of disabled = true. My solution doesn't render a greyed out checkbox, but when the user clicks nothing happens

Comment: It does force you to add an `apex:form` tag to the page though.

Comment: And unnecessary since output field works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The `<apex:outputField value="{!your Value}"/>`shows the check box with tick mark. The other methods like `<apex:inputcheckbox disabled=true>` also work but I found this visually good.